# Anyone ever tried to develop in C or C++ for Blackberry platforms?

Tags: blackberry, native

Every indication I have, based on my experience in embedded computing is that doing something like this would require expensive equipment to get access to the platform (ICE debuggers, JTAG probes, I2C programmers, etc, etc), but I've always wondered if some ambitious hacker out there has found a way to load native code on a Blackberry device.   Anyone?

Edit: I'm aware of the published SDK and it's attendant restrictions.  I'm curious if anyone has attempted to get around them, and if so, how far they got.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've seen this question pop up in a number of different forums over time. The original Blackberries were programmable in C++ but I think that RIM ran up against the problems of trying to implement a secure platform in the C/C++ compile to native paradigm.

The devices do have JTAG ports, but unless one could get hands on the RIM code as a place to start the problem is enormous.

I also have to wonder how useful a Blackberry with a replacement FOSS operating system would be, since it would not likely have the protocols to connect to BES or BIS, send PIN's etc. If one was simply looking for a the power of the hand held computing platform I suspect there are many more likely candidates available.

Answer (score 3):

No, C++ is no longer a supported RIM development tool, as they phased it out a number of years ago. Client applications can be developed in Java (or one of a few 5GL frameworks), and web + sever-side apps can be developed using standard tools.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for updated information, the new Playbook os, also known as QNX, also known as Blackberry 10 (or it will be when the phones running it come out) is in fact c/c++ based, also using QML and a C++ add on called Cascades.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the official [SDK website](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/) only seems to mention Java.  According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry#CPU), different versions of the BlackBerry use different processors.  Combined with the fact that RIM uses a proprietary operating system for the devices, it becomes pretty difficult to develop native code without official tools.  There is also a partial API-level security restriction which would further prohibit advanced tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

Just randomly searching for an answer to this and came across http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Native-C-C-SDK/td-p/778009 which mentions that BB intend to release a C/C++ SDK soon, more details will be provided at the 2011 Game Developer Conference.