# Can I develop Blackberry applications using C# .NET on windows7

Tags: c#, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Hey, I have a keen interest to build an application for blackberry OS, can I do it with C#?

Also Blackberry has launched a plug-in for Visual Studio but how would you use it along with the simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you talk about [BlackBerry Plug-in for Microsoft Visual Studio 1.2](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/visualstudio.jsp):

> The BlackBerry® Plug-in for Microsoft® Visual Studio® allows web developers to leverage existing Microsoft® based developer tools to create and debug web projects for BlackBerry smartphones.

- see [video lesson](http://www.blackberry.com/DevMediaLibrary/view.do?name=PluginforMicrosoftVisualStudio)
- read [Debugging Your First Web Application In Microsoft Visual Studio](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/Debugging_Your_First_Web_Application_In_Microsofft_Visual_Studio.pdf)
- look into [VS plugin docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Plug-in+for+Microsoft+Visual+Studio) and [related KB articles](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=1366148&objAction=browse&sort=name)

Comment: Does this allow you to use C#? It just looks like a local browser application widget thingie, with a plugin for developing it in VS.

Answer (score 7):

No. You can't do it. You have got to use Java to do [Blackberry development](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/). There use to be a C/C++ API for blackberry but it is no longer supported.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134408/anyone-ever-tried-to-develop-in-c-or-c-for-blackberry-platforms) stackoverflow question out.

Comment: -1, there are also RAD MDS studio and web development plugins

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source project: http://code.google.com/p/csharpblackberry/

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry Introduced Plugin for Visual Studio. But supported language is Java for developing BB app. You cant develop your app in C#.