# blackberry apps using c#

Tags: blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I develop blackberry applications using C#.NET on windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109463/can-i-develop-blackberry-applications-using-c-net-on-windows7)

can anybody give me any idea?
is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first search in textbox at upper right corner and then post

refer to this:

[Can I develop Blackberry applications using C# .NET on windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109463/can-i-develop-blackberry-applications-using-c-net-on-windows7)

Comment: thank u for helping me and guiding abt stackoverflow searching

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you cannot develop BlackBerry apps in C#. You need to write Java code for BlackBerry.

Longer answer: dig through [the link posted in Swati's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405559/blackberry-apps-using-c/4405564#4405564).